# how to take a picture of one linearlayout in android studio?

Tags: android, image, view

I would like take a picture of a part of activity sub layout.
so..
activity itself will be FrameLayout
and FrameLayout includes some other views like Toolbar, ImageView, TextView etc..

and I would like to make a JPEG picture into my sd card in order to store just a sublayout of parent layout.

I have tried to look the way on google and I found a solution which has been obsolated in android studio

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You complete full source like..

```
 private void snapScreen() {
    View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
    // View v1 = iv.getRootView(); //even this works
    View v1 = findViewById(R.id.main_result); //this works too for particular view
    // but gives only content
    Bitmap myBitmap;
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    myBitmap = v1.getDrawingCache();
    snap.saveBitmap(myBitmap, IntentResultItem);
}
```

---

***For create Snapshot***

**Make sure you give permission for external storage**

```
public class SendSnap {

Context mContext;

public SendSnap(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
}


public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, String msg) {

    String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "screenshot.png";
    File imagePath = new File(filePath);
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

```
//Define a bitmap with height and width of the View
Bitmap viewBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(),v.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

Canvas viewCanvas = new Canvas(viewBitmap);

//get background of canvas
Drawable backgroundDrawable = v.getBackground();

if(backgroundDrawable!=null){
backgroundDrawable.draw(viewCanvas);//draw the background on canvas;
}
else{
viewCanvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN);
//draw on canvas
v.draw(viewCanvas) 
}

//write the above generated bitmap  to a file
String fileStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        try{
            imgFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),fileStamp+".jpg");
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imgFile);
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,40,outputStream);
            outputStream.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Don't forget to add this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```