# Saved Bitmap to PNG File randomly goes black

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I'm processing about 4 images / seconds from camera preview, save it to png File and send it to a server.

I couldn't yet identify why, but 1 time out of 2 the current session will store the .png as full black pictures. the File size is also very small (3kb vs the usual 700kb).

**Here's how I store the Bitmap as a PNG file :**

```
public static File SaveImagePNG(Bitmap subimg, String path, String filename) {
        FileOutputStream out = null;

    File sd = new File(path);
    boolean success = true;
    if (!sd.exists()) {
        success = sd.mkdir();
    }
    if (success) {
        File dest = new File(sd, filename);

        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(dest);
            if (subimg != null) {
                // PNG is a lossless format, the compression factor (100) is ignored
                subimg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); // bmp is your Bitmap instance
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (out != null) {
                    out.close();
                    Log.d(TAG, "OK!!");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage() + "Error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return dest;
    }
    return null;
}
```

**and here's how I call it :**

```
        val pathFilePNG = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/images"

        requestParams[0]?.bitmapRGB?.setHasAlpha(false)
        val imageFaceRGBFile = BitmapUtils.SaveImagePNG(requestParams[0]?.bitmapRGB, pathFilePNG, "faceRGB.png")
```

Comment: `"faceRGB.png"` You are not using the same filename for all files do you?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/42622825/5094531
Try saving your bitmap to Canvas and Drawable

Comment: @blackapps That was the problem, I'd sometimes interrupt the conversion while shutting the app, therefore randomly being black. A bit silly but eh.